# Creating links between nodes d3.js currently returning Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I have the following json structure:

```
data = {  
           "nodes":[  
              {  
                 "nodeType":"File",
                 "nodeId":16392,
                 "property1":"coint_ctolocal_partitions",
                 "property2":null,
                 "group":0,
                 "more":false
              },
              {  
                 "nodeType":"File",
                 "nodeId":16386,
                 "property1":"pers_contrato_partitions",
                 "property2":null,
                 "group":0,
                 "more":false
              }
           ],
           "links":[  
              {  
                 "source":16386,
                 "target":16392,
                 "value":0,
                 "val":"{\"Contract\":[\"Insurance\"]}",
                 "type":"PTN"
              }
           ]
        };
```

Currently this is returning `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined`.

In our test data we simply used `source:0` and `target:1` and this works as I assume it is using the index of nodes to link the objects together. Or perhaps the `linkindex` function.

The full function looks like this:

```
returnTableRelationshipData = function(){

        data = {} // json data as described above  

        // used to store the number of links between two nodes. 
        // mLinkNum[data.links[i].source + "," + data.links[i].target] = data.links[i].linkindex;
        var mLinkNum = {};

        // sort links first
        sortLinks();                                

        // set up linkIndex and linkNumer, because it may possible multiple links share the same source and target node
        setLinkIndexAndNum();

        // check that we don't have empty or null values
        checkDataNotEmpty();

        var w = 600,
            h = 500;

        var force = d3.layout.force()
                    .nodes(d3.values(data.nodes))
                    .links(data.links)
                    .size([w, h])
                    .linkDistance(150)
                    .charge(-300)
                    .on("tick", tick)
                    .start();

        var svg = d3.select(".graphContainer").append("svg:svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        var path = svg.append("svg:g")
                    .selectAll("path")
                    .data(force.links())
                    .enter().append("svg:path")
                    .attr("class", "link");

        var circle = svg.append("svg:g")
                    .selectAll("circle")
                    .data(force.nodes())
                    .enter().append("svg:circle")
                    .attr("r", 6)
                    .call(force.drag);

        var text = svg.append("svg:g")                                
                    .selectAll("g")
                    .data(force.nodes())
                    .enter().append("svg:g");

        // A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
        text.append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", 12)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .attr("class", "shadow")
            .text(function(d){ return d.property1; });   

        text.append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", 12)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .text(function(d){ return d.property1; });

        // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
        function tick() {
            path.attr("d", function(d){
                var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                    dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                // get the total link numbers between source and target node
                var lTotalLinkNum = mLinkNum[d.source.id + "," + d.target.id] || mLinkNum[d.target.id + "," + d.source.id];
                if(lTotalLinkNum > 1)
                {
                    // if there are multiple links between these two nodes, we need generate different dr for each path
                    dr = dr/(1 + (1/lTotalLinkNum) * (d.linkindex - 1));
                }       
                // generate svg path
                return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + 
                    "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 1," + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y + 
                    "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 0," + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y;    
            });

            circle.attr("transform", function(d){
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });

            text.attr("transform", function(d){
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });
        } 

        // sort the links by source, then target
        function sortLinks(){
            if(data.links != null){                         
                data.links.sort(function(a,b){
                    if(a.source > b.source){
                        return 1;
                    }else if(a.source < b.source){
                        return -1;
                    }else{
                        if(a.target > b.target){
                            return 1;
                        }if(a.target < b.target){
                            return -1;
                        }else{
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        //any links with duplicate source and target get an incremented 'linknum'
        function setLinkIndexAndNum(){                              
            for(var i = 0; i < data.links.length; i++){
                if(i != 0 &&
                    data.links[i].source == data.links[i-1].source &&
                    data.links[i].target == data.links[i-1].target){
                    data.links[i].linkindex = data.links[i-1].linkindex + 1;
                }else{
                    data.links[i].linkindex = 1;
                }// save the total number of links between two nodes
                if(mLinkNum[data.links[i].target + "," + data.links[i].source] !== undefined){
                    mLinkNum[data.links[i].target + "," + data.links[i].source] = data.links[i].linkindex;
                }else{
                    mLinkNum[data.links[i].source + "," + data.links[i].target] = data.links[i].linkindex;
                }
            }
        }

        function checkDataNotEmpty(){
            data.links.forEach(function(link, index, list) {
                if (typeof link.source === 'undefined') {
                    console.log('undefined link', data.nodes[link.source]);
                }
                if (typeof link.target === 'undefined') {
                    console.log('undefined source', data.nodes[link.target]);
                }
                console.log(typeof link.source, typeof link.target);
            });
        }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    returnTableRelationshipData();
});
```

In the nodes data we have `nodeId` which identifies the node uniquely. We also have `property1` which is a unique table name.

So I need some way to set the source and target between the existing data using custom json keys, if this is possible? (ie map nodeId to be source or target).

At first I thought I was getting issues with integers, strings and so on, but we can convert between these if it will help. (I mean I did try this but to no success).

I have made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/j1q1oLzL/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this to convert the target /source id to it index in nodes array:

```
//find the node index
function find(f){
  var i = -1
    data.nodes.forEach(function(node, index){
        if(node.nodeId == f)
            i = index;
    });
    return i;
}
//set the source and target index
data.links.forEach(function(d){
            d.source = find(d.source);
            d.target = find(d.target);
        });
```

The link source target has to be index of the node array as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#links)

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/3v4r1sjs/)

Comment: Oh thanks, that looks great, I will try that out shortly.